# Replacing DIVs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this HTML structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="game1">Game 1</div>
    <div id="game2">Game 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="game3">Game 3</div>
    <div id="game4" class="fav">Game 4 (fav)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="game5" class="fav">Game 5 (fav)</div>
    <div id="game6">Game 6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="game7">Game 7</div>
    <div id="game8"class="fav">Game 8 (fav)</div>
</div>
```

I need to sort these by favorites (`class=fav`). Here's what I do for that:

```
    var favs  = [];
    var rest  = [];

    var items = $('body').find('.row').each( function() { 
        $(this).children('div').each( function(i) {
            if ( $(this).hasClass('fav') ) { 
                favs.push( $(this) );
            }
            else {
                rest.push( $(this) );
            }
        }); 
    });
```

My issue is that I need to go through each item in `items` which would be the `<div>` of `class=row` and replace the child `<divs>` with `id=game#`. Here is my attempt at that:

```
$(items).each( function() {
        $(this).children('div').each( function() {

            if ( favs.length == 0 ) {
                //use rest[]
                myText = $(rest[0]);

                $(this).text( $(myText).text() );
                rest.splice(0, 1);
            }

            else {
                //use favs[];
                toUse = $(favs[0]);
                $(this).text( $(toUse).text() );
                favs.splice(0, 1);
            }

        });
    });
```

It looks like what is happening is that when I begin to write over the text of the current div, it is replacing something in my `rest` array. I have made sure 1,000 times that `rest` doesn't contain any of those values, but they are still getting printed out. Here is what the output looks like:

```
Game 4 (fav)
Game 5 (fav)
Game 8 (fav)
Game 4 (fav)
Game 5 (fav)
Game 8 (fav)
Game 8 (fav)
Game 8 (fav)
```

So Game 4 (fav), Game 5 (fav), and Game 8 (fav) are supposed to be in `favs` and they are getting printed out correctly, everything after the first three is what is wrong.

Result should be:

```
Game 4 (fav)
Game 5 (fav)
Game 8 (fav) 
Game 1
Game 2
Game 3
Game 6
Game 7
```

Can someone offer some insight into what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: rest[r] and favs[f]. What are the "r" and "f" vars set to? Also - here is a quick fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/qhnDD/

Comment: oh, sorry. forgot to replace them in a couple places. they aren't terribly necessary, both are set to 0s. I thought I would need to separate indices to maintain track of where I am in each array, but since I'm removing each item from the array as I use, it's always going to be 0.

Comment: what should be the final result?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add it to the end.

Comment: @MattAltepeter nevermind. see my answer please. I think it is more clean. Also the answer you accepted has flaws. If you look closer you get something like this `<div id="game3">Game 8 (fav)</div>` in your DOM.

Comment: Correct, I was replicating what he was doing, my final answer moves the actual divs which keeps the id's and classes in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest a different approach? I think you are complicating it.

Also using @Robert McKee solution you get something like this: `<div id="game3">Game 8 (fav)</div>`, and it seems wrong.

How about this:

```
var $favs = $(".row .fav").remove();
var $rest = $(".row div").remove();

var i = 0;
$(".row").each(function () {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        var elem = (i < $favs.length) ? $favs.eq(i) : $rest.eq(i - $favs.length);
        $(this).append(elem);
        i++;
    }
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sVFxe/)**

Comment: Yes, I was just replicating what his code was doing.  My last solution moves the divs which keeps them in sync with the text, but I believe in a clearer way than the above solution.

Comment: Can you offer a suggestion on if I wanted to only remove a certain number of the non favorite divs? I have to start optimizing this a bit more and don't want to remove 1000 divs if I only need to remove 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that favs and rest are actually references to the divs, and if you change the text within them, the reference remains the same, so when you go to pick up the text later, it isn't what it was when you first iterated it.  So you replace "Game 1" in `#game1` with "Game 4 (fav)", and you have a reference to it in rest[0].  When you then try to process rest, the text of rest[0] is "Game 4 (fav)".  The solution is to push the text values instead of DOM references.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var favs  = [];
    var rest  = [];

    var items = $('.row > div');
    items.each( function() { 
            if ( $(this).hasClass('fav') ) { 
                favs.push( $(this).text() );
            }
            else {
                rest.push( $(this).text() );
            }
    });

    items.each( function() {
            if ( favs.length == 0 ) {
                //use rest[]
                myText = rest.shift();
                $(this).text(myText);
              }

            else {
                //use favs[];
                toUse = favs.shift();
                $(this).text(toUse);
            }
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhnDD/11/

Alternatively:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var favs  = [];
    var rest  = [];

    var items = $('.row > div');
    items.each( function() { 
            if ( $(this).hasClass('fav') ) { 
                favs.push( $(this).text() );
            }
            else {
                rest.push( $(this).text() );
            }
    });
    favs=favs.concat(rest);
    items.each( function() {
        $(this).text(favs.shift());
    });
});
```

And for the ultra compact version:

```
var all = $('.row .fav').remove().toArray()
   .concat($('.row div').remove().toArray());
$('.row').each(function () {
        $(this).append(all.shift());
        $(this).append(all.shift());
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhnDD/23/

Comment: Wow thanks. Really appreciate this. Do you know what I was doing incorrectly?

Comment: Wow, stackoverflow is lagged today, I just got your comment.  I've updated the answer with the reason, and two better versions of the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use .splice() in this scenario. You should be using .pop() or .shift().

Comment: Can you expand on that? Specifically how it relates to their original problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at it . . . it works, but admittedly, I'm tired, so it might no be the most efficient code that I've ever written.   :D

**The JS:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //the parent div needs to be accessible to the function
    var $sortParent;

    // set up a new row div for cloning and initialize the current row
    var $newRow = $("<div></div>").addClass("row");
    var $currentRow = $newRow.clone();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // initialize the parent div
        $sortParent = $(".divSort");

        //get all of the original rows
        var $currentRows = $sortParent.find(".row");

        // get the favorite games
        var $favorites = $currentRows.find(".fav");
        // get the other games
        var $others = $currentRows.find(":not(.fav)");

        // re-add the favorite games at the top
        $favorites.each(function(){
            addGame($(this));
        });
        // re-add the other games a the bottom
        $others.each(function(){
            addGame($(this));
        });

        // if the current row only has one game in it, it needs to be added now
        if ($currentRow.children().length === 1) {
            $sortParent.append($currentRow);
        }
        // remove all of the original rows
        $currentRows.remove();
    });

    // function that adds a game to a new row
    function addGame(currentGame) {
        // add the current game to the current row
        $currentRow.append(currentGame);

        // if the current row already has 2 games in it, append it to the parent and set up a new row
        if ($currentRow.children().length > 1) {
            $sortParent.append($currentRow);
            $currentRow = $newRow.clone();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**The starting HTML:**

```
<div class="divSort">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game1">Game 1</div>
        <div id="game2">Game 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game3">Game 3</div>
        <div id="game4" class="fav">Game 4 (fav)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game5" class="fav">Game 5 (fav)</div>
        <div id="game6">Game 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game7">Game 7</div>
        <div id="game8"class="fav">Game 8 (fav)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The resulting HTML:**

```
<div class="divSort">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fav" id="game4">Game 4 (fav)</div>
        <div class="fav" id="game5">Game 5 (fav)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fav" id="game8">Game 8 (fav)</div>
        <div id="game1">Game 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game2">Game 2</div>
        <div id="game3">Game 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="game6">Game 6</div>
        <div id="game7">Game 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```